# I'm having problems writing test for my Solidity contract?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I really do not understand what the typeError is on my first test. Can someone take a look at is and tell me what the problem is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wh86.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gAhS.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO ! Please try to include your relevant code as actual text in the post, not just as image.

Answer (score 1):

There is a small typo in your code, maybe this already fixes your problem :

In your code you wrote :

```js
let LifeInsurance = null;

/* and then */
lifeInsurance = await LifeInsurance.deployed();
```

*Note the small typo for LifeInsurance vs. lifeInsurance*

I think your code should look like this

```js
let lifeInsurance = null; // small "L" here

/* and then */
lifeInsurance = await LifeInsurance.deployed();
```